# OpenShift (OKD) 4 change infrastructure image source

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-4

I've got a disconnected OKD 4.9 installation with an internal harbor registry for deploying the infrastructure itself and application images.

I'd like to change from an disconnected installation to an "online" respectively an proxied installation without redeployment of the whole infrastructure. I've already added our internal proxy server and changed the ImageContentSourcePolicy but still [image: okd release image url]

I can't find the regarding configuration for the image source.

Any ideas how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Openshift Slack Group I've managed to change from a disconnected installation with a local mirror registry to a proxied installation.

You have to change the "ClusterVersion" yaml to:

```
spec:
  channel: stable-4
  upstream: 'https://amd64.origin.releases.ci.openshift.org/graph'
  desiredUpdate:
    image: >-  registry.ci.openshift.org/origin/release@sha256:a506d80873f7c51201c614be9c8defa6455f3b593faa54d11ded7b4d20c0fc4e
```

This would enable an upgrade to 4.11